# Creating a JWT With ECDSA P-256 SHA-256 With PHP

Tags: php, cryptography, jwt, digital-signature, xbox-one

I'm wondering if it's possible to properly create a signature using the P256 curve and PHP. OpenSSL in PHP has support for creating the key and getting the proper things in order.

According to this documentation - http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-jones-json-web-token-01.html#DefiningECDSA - Section 8.3 states:

> A JWT is signed with an ECDSA P-256 SHA-256 signature as follows:
>
> 1. Generate a digital signature of the UTF-8 representation of the JWT Signing Input using ECDSA P-256 SHA-256 with the desired private key. The output will be the EC point (R, S), where R and S are unsigned integers.
> 2. Turn R and S into byte arrays in big endian order. Each array will be 32 bytes long.
> 3. Concatenate the two byte arrays in the order R and then S.
> 4. Base64url encode the 64 byte array as defined in this specification.

Herein the problem lies with getting the R and S byte arrays.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
//Create Array Configuration
$config = array(
    "curve_name" => "prime256v1",
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
);
$ourkey = openssl_pkey_new($config);

/* We would get the key details to help extract out other information such as x/y coord 
of curve and private key but it's not necessary to show for this part*/

// Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
openssl_pkey_export($ourkey, $privKey);

$data = "Example data we will be using to sign";
$data = hash("sha256", $data);

$signature = "";
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $privKey); // Should I include the digest algo in this call as well?
```

The problem here is that this signature is not R and S that I can use to concatenate together to make the real signature I need... I think.

So ultimately, is there any way I can get the R and S values from a openssl function in php?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don’t you use a PHP library that do it well? You will find some of them that support ES256, 384 or 512 signature algorithms at https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something *like* JWT but not JWT in particular, consider [PASETO](https://paseto.io).

Assuming you opt for v2, PASETO doesn't use ECDSA, it uses the more secure EdDSA over Ed25519. Furthermore, the standard goes out of its way to be [boring](https://cr.yp.to/talks/2015.10.05/slides-djb-20151005-a4.pdf) so that implementations will be obviously secure.

(If you opt for v1, PASETO uses RSASSA-PSS.)

If you **do** need JWT in particular, look no further than [lcobucci/jwt](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt), which in turn uses [PHPECC](https://github.com/phpecc/phpecc) for ECDSA.

Once upon a time, PHPECC was riddled with side-channel vulnerabilities which made it a bad choice to use in production systems. These days, it's about as secure as a PHP implementation of ECDSA could be. I wrote a usability wrapper called [easy-ecc](https://github.com/paragonie/easy-ecc) if anyone wants to use PHPECC in only the safest configuration.

Luís Cobucci's JWT library is the only PHP implementation of JWT that has, to my knowledge, been formally audited by a security company. The report is public and lives [here](https://paragonie.com/audit/UGCwpFmaIkQ085l7).

Answer (score 0):

these functions have helped me to encode and decode signatures generated with curve, i hope this help.

to encode:

```
function encode_signature() {
    $data = "HOLA";

$private_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCDKuYJPma+sA2svl02CPCJECESuBrW2nExuUR1vtHgozw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;

    $binary_signature = "";
    openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
    $valid_signature = base64_encode($binary_signature);

    return $valid_signature;
}
```

to decode:

```
function decode_signature($signature) {
    $data = "HOLA";

$public_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE/kmRxyn5LUQdC3owkWDp6DkLnTlBN2VPd86FS5WAqQJA4y9oaowYYVSu0A7kv8tUa9FLAqb7UPfUNeh5zDnrFQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOD;

    $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($public_key);
    $verify = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), $publicKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

    return (bool) $verify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the key pair to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. It worked the first time with the same PHP code.
To me, it looks like a PHP / OpenSSL problem / bug with ECDSA key pairs.

I know this question is older, but because I played a lot with web crypto API generated key pairs and signatures and tried to verify what's here with PHP `openssl_verify()` method...

The functions above look good, but aren't working for me in much tested variants. Tried different OS bases (centos, alpine) and PHP versions (7.4, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3), but each time verify an ECDSA signature fails with "-1".

After trying the other things mentioned in answers here and failing, I used the solution mentioned above of moving the key pair to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5.